# How do __enter__ and __exit__ work in Python decorator classes?

Tags: python, class, count, decorator, exit

I'm trying to create a decorator class that counts how many times a function is called, but I'm getting an error message that says:

```
    "TypeError: __exit__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)"
```

and I really don't know how I'm giving it four arguments.  My code looks like this:

```
class fcount2(object):
    __instances = {}
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.__f = f
        self.__numcalls = 0
        fcount2.__instances[f] = self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__numcalls += 1
        return self.__f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self):
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def count(f):
        return fcount2.__instances[self.__f].__numcalls


@fcount2
def f(n):
    return n+2

for n in range(5):
    print f(n)   
print 'f count =',f.count

def foo(n):
    return n*n

with fcount2(foo) as g:
    print g(1)
    print g(2)
print 'g count =',g.count
print 'f count =',f.count

with fcount2(f) as g:
    print g(1)
    print g(2)
print 'g count =',g.count
print 'f count =',f.count

with f:
    print f(1)
    print g(2)
print 'g count =',g.count
print 'f count =',f.count
```

Are there some other parameters I should (or shouldn't) be passing into the def **exit** function?  Any tips or ideas would be appreciated.

As an aside, my line of code that says "print 'f count =',f.count" appears to be outputting the memory address rather than the value, but that's a whole different problem.

Comment: What behavior do you want the context manager to have?  in other words, decorators and context managers are 2 very different things that serve different purposes... e.g. why are you trying to make a context manager here?

Comment: I was trying to keep a separate counter for the number of times the "with" called the function and the total number of times the function was called overall.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

the `__exit__()` method should accept information about exceptions that come up in the `with:` block. See [here](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__).

The following modification of your code works:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
    if exc_type is not None:
        traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
        # return False # uncomment to pass exception through

    return True
```

Then you can try raising an exception in one of your `with:` blocks and it'll be caught in `__exit__()`.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why you are getting that error is becuase `__exit__()` takes 3 arguments along with `self`. These are:

1. exception_type
2. exception_value
3. traceback

You can define `__exit__()` method two ways:

```
def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
```

or

```
def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

`with` statement supports the concept of a runtime context defined by a context manager implemented using `__enter__()` & `__exit__()` method pair. Please visit this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__exit__#context-manager-types) for detailed info.

`__enter__()` method will enter the runtime context and return either this object or another object related to the runtime context.

`__exit__()` method will exit the runtime context and return a Boolean flag indicating if any exception that occurred should be suppressed. The values of these arguments contain information regarding the thrown exception. **If the values equal to None means no exception was thrown.**